# Zipster alternative for macOS High Sierra

Tags: file-compression, zip, macos

[Zipster](https://coriolis-systems.com/Zipster/) integrates support for browsing compressed files on macOS Finder but it's been discontinued. The website says:

> **Support for this product has ended.** There are known problems with this
>   product on recent versions of the macOS; in particular, it is known to
>   trigger kernel panics on some versions of the kernel when Zip files
>   are ejected. This is caused by kernel bugs and the only possible
>   workaround would be to completely rewrite Zipster to work in a
>   different manner.

Is there any other tool one can use to browser compressed files on macOS High Sierra, preferable one that's free or open source?